# How to save Sharepoint SPFx property pane data permanently?

Tags: spfx

How do we permanently store this data? For eg. I've a carousel component and I gave the autoPlay enable option in property pane, so user can configure the carousel. How I save this autoPlay property value (true/false), without loosing it when user is refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page is in edit mode, assuming the setting has been implemented as a web part property, it should be automatically persisted.

Comment: How to persist if the page is not n the edit mode? How to force it manually ? I tried this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(targetProperty, oldValue, newValue); but it doesnot work

Comment: If the page is not in edit mode, the properties won't be persisted, at least not in web part properties. You could store them in a cookie or local storage, but not in web part properties.

Comment: If I use a global variable, For 2 webparts it overrides the settings of first

Comment: Users can put multiple instances of the same web part on the page, so you'd have to store them in key-value pairs, where the key is the instanceId of the particular web part.